# Solarized leaving red highlighting at the end of lines in vim

Tags: vim, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vimrc, solarized

I'm using vim with the solarized dark color scheme within the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Solarized looks great except for one strange feature. When I scroll down in a vim file and then scroll back up, the empty space at the ends of the lines that were hidden when I scrolled down are highlighted in a distracting red color.

[image]

I have an imperfect workaround. By running `:set background=dark` within vim, the red highlighting temporarily goes away, but I am looking for a more permanent solution.

Here is the relevant section of my `.vimrc` file:

```
 syntax enable
 set background=dark
 let g:solarized_termcolors=256
 colorscheme solarized
```

I installed vim from [altercation/vim-colors-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) repository using the manual installation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Following the instructions posted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832#issuecomment-493747616), I added `set t_ut=""` to my `.vimrc` file.